# permission denied while trying to copy files from local server to remote server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working in a remote server,i need some files from my local server.I am using the following commands for copy files from local server to my remote server

```
rsync -v -e ssh /home/tanveer/myfilename username@server:/path-in-serve
```

but i am facing a 'Permission denied' exception.The Error is..

```
rsync: mkstemp "/home/.shutterstock.tar.gz.dIldLF" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 10161405 bytes  received 31 bytes  131115.30 bytes/sec
total size is 10160081  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at    main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

My question is that whether the command is right for copying files from local server to remote server?If it is ,how do i get permission to copy the files.

Comment: Check it please,i have edited my post to show the actual error  user2486495

Comment: In place of **/path-in-serve** type **/home/your-user-name**.  Here your-user-name is your actual user name on remote system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is correct, but I expect you are trying to copy the files to the wrong location. Have you tried copying the files to your `home` directory?

```
rsync -v -e ssh /home/tanveer/myfilename username@server:~
```

You can also shorten your command by leaving out the `-e ssh` which is normally set by default. You might also want to preserve the copied files' properties `-a`, copy symlinks as symlinks `-l` and limit your copying to a single partition `-x`:

```
rsync -valx /home/tanveer/myfilename username@server:~
```

One thing to look out for when using `rsync` is the effect of adding a trailing `/` to a source directory. Without a trailing `/` the directory will be copied as a directory, with the trailing `/` only its contents will be copied.

Comment: rsync -v -e ssh /codes/shutterstock.tar.gz  username@server:/home *andrew.punnett*